# Blocking the possibility to create classes directly bypassing a factory

Tags: php, factory, base-class

In a base class for all the models in our MVC  system, I created a factory method BaseCLass::getNew() that returns an instance of the requested child class when called via SomeChildClass::getNew().

Now, I'm looking for a way to force the programmer to use this factory. I.e., idially I'd like that any class created directly, like this:

```
 new SomeChildClass
```

will throw an exception upon creation, and only classes created by the factory will be usable.

Any ideas how can this be achieved?

Our code is written in PHP, but good chance that your idea will be valuable even if you think on a different language.

edit: I cannot make my constructor private, as the framework constructor in the class that I inherit is public, and php would not allow me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making the class have a private [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

### Update -- solution that covers your stated requirements

```
class Base {
    private static $constructorToken = null;

    protected static function getConstructorToken() {
        if (self::$constructorToken === null) {
            self::$constructorToken = new stdClass;
        }

        return self::$constructorToken;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public function __construct($token) {
        if ($token !== parent::getConstructorToken()) {
            die ("Attempted to construct manually");
        }
    }

    public static function makeMeOne() {
        return new Derived(parent::getConstructorToken());
    }
}
```

This solution takes advantage of the object equality rules for `stdClass` by storing a "magic password" object on the base class which only derived classes can access. You can tweak it to taste.

I wouldn't call it *horrible* like the `debug_backtrace` idea, but still I have the impression that things should be done differently.

Comment: Any way to enforce this from the level of the base class? I'd like to avoid defining this private constructors to all subClasses

Comment: I cannot make my constructor protected, as the constructor in the  framework class that I inherit is public, and php would not allow me this.

Comment: @gidireich: Then you should rethink if you are going the right way. I can think of voodoo to achieve your stated goal, but it's the "you shouldn't be caught dead doing this" kind. Maybe you can satisfy your business requirements without needing all construction to go through the factory methods?

Comment: Yeah, go ahead, give me your vodoo! I'm currently thinking of a debug_backtrace vodoo by the way, but let's hear yours

Comment: @gidireich: That was the one I was thinking of as well ;)

Comment: Can you educate me why *exactly* it's a vodoo?

Comment: @gidireich: Because it's just *bad* on many levels. In all respect, if I was asked this question in an interview I 'd interpret it as "this guy is willing to do anything, no matter how wrong, to get the code to run" and *immediately* recommend no hire. On the bright side, I came up with something not as bad; check it out.

Comment: At this point, I'd either pull the framework library file and edit the visibility myself, or just tell my boss "sorry, not a feature of the language yet", and just wait for traits.

Comment: The constructor parameter thing is a good direction, and I didn't even find a need in using the stdClass magic. Just passing an agreed value from the factory method, is in practice 100% safe that no developer will call the constructor directly by accident.

Answer (score 2):

By making the constructor of the child class `protected`.  The parent class will have access to all protected methods of the child.  Any attempt to directly create the child (ie: `new child`) will cause a fatal error.

```
<?php

class factory
{

    static public function create()
    {
        return new child;
    }

}

class child extends factory
{

    protected function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Ok';
    }

}

$c = factory::create(); // Ok
$c2 = new child; // fatal error

?>
```

Though this method won't let you throw an exception instead :(

If then absolutely necessary, only [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function comes to mind (besides using singleton for the child itself, or forced object pool patterns using and passing GUID's generated by factory and verified by child).  Within the child constructor, look at the 2nd array value to make sure "function" === "create" and "class" === "factory.  Throw exception if not matching.  I didn't suggest this initially, only because I suspect using `debug_backtrace` may give a performance hit.

Comment: This will not work for me, as the constructor of *my* parent is already public and I can't change it. In your example this means that factory extend ParentOfFactoryAFrameworkClass

Comment: @gidireich: sorry, missed that part.  Attempting to raise the visibility of a child method would indeed cause a fatal error.  I'm not aware of any way to overcome that, except what I just added to my answer.

Comment: Actually, the debug_trace solution suits in this contexts. The code calling for it can be marked to run only on development and not on production, which is good enough for any practical need.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the class's constructor private, and it can only be called from within the class's own methods like `getNew()`.

Comment: I cannot make my constructor private/protected, as the constructor in the framework class that I inherit, is public, and php would not allow me this.

Comment: @gid Then write a wrapper class which contains an instance of the framework class, rather than inheritng from the class directly. Choose **composition** instead of **inheritance**. There is no external way to prevent a class from being instantiated with `new`; you necessarily have to be able to change the functionality of the class from within the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways to implement it

- make parent class private use magic
- user magic function __autoload; check the type of class and through error with not allowed message

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: "make parent class private use magic" - do not understand what it means, can you clarify?

Comment: as for the second suggestion, what do you mean by checking the class? It'll be invariably some sublcass of my class, but how this information will help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define constructor of the class private or protected. But if you cannot do it, you can control where an object of the class is created in the constructor:

```
trait FactoryChecking
{
    protected function checkFactory(string $factoryClass): void
    {
        $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        foreach($trace as $traceItem) {
            if ($traceItem['class'] == $factoryClass) {
                return;
            }
        }   
        throw new Exception('Cannot create class ' . static::class . ' outside of factory');
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    use FactoryChecking;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkFactory(Factory::class);
    }
}

class Factory
{
    public function create(): ClassA
    {
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```

Details I described in the article "[Forbidding of creating objects outside factory in PHP](https://medium.com/@marenkov/forbidding-of-creating-objects-outside-factory-in-php-7173d7be6cb4)"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31351852)